# How to find .pc files for pkg-config via Conan and CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, pkg-config, conan

How can I make pkg-config find both dependencies installed via Conan AND dependencies that are not in Conan?

My target package is built using CMake and finds its dependencies using pkg-config with `pkg_check_modules()`. One of the dependencies (`glib-2.0`) is installed via Conan, another (`libsecret-1`) isn't, as there's no package.

In my conanfile I'm configuring the pkg-config_installer as a build requirement (`self.build_requires("pkg-config_installer/0.29.2@bincrafters/stable")`. When building the package, CMake correctly invokes this pkg-config.

As a result, pkg-config finds glib just fine, but it cannot find libsecret. I assume it finds `.pc` files for dependencies installed via Conan, but doesn't find `libsecret-1.pc`, which is located in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/` on my system.

I tried telling Conan's CMake tool to use this path: `tools.PkgConfig("libsecret-1").variables["pcfiledir"]` tells me where it is and the CMake tool's configure method has a `pkg_config_paths` parameter. Unfortunately, this changes nothing.

Comment: Take a look on the documentation: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/pkg_config_pc_files.html You have 3 different approaches for customizing the prefix. You can append PKG_CONFIG_PATH, set --define-prefix argument or even set PKG_CONFIG_$PACKAGE_$VARIABLE

Answer (score 0):

The following steps made it work for me:

- set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to the `pcfiledir` found by `tools.PkgConfig`
- do not to pass any `pkg_config_paths` to `tools.CMake.configure()`, it doesn't handle absolute paths well and conflicts with the environment variable
- add the system-wide installed lib (`secret-1` in my case) to `cpp_info.system_libs` in the `package_info` step

Thanks @uilianries for the helpful comment!